# Custom scrollbar thumb not being applied to ListFragment with Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar activity

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-drawable

For some reason my custom drawable will not apply as a custom fast scroll thumb when declaring it in `styles.xml`. I really don't get why it's not changing when something like this should be straight forward. How can a custom drawable be used for the fast scroll thumb when using the `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` theme?

**Manifest**

```
<activity
    android:name=".fruit.FruitActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
```

**fragment_withfastscroll.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="OrangeTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:fastScrollPreviewBackgroundRight">@drawable/fastscrollpreview_orange</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollOverlayPosition">atThumb</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/fastscrollthumb_orange</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollTextColor">#fff</item>
</style>
```

**FruitListAdapter.java**

```
public class FruitLineListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SectionIndexer {

    private List<Fruit> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private Object[] mSections;
    private int[] mSectionsIndexedByPosition;
    private int[] mPositionsIndexedBySection;

    public FruitListAdapter(List<Fruit> data, Context context) {
        mData = data;
        mData = new ArrayList(mData);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        setupSections();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        FruitListAdapter.ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_dualline, parent, false);
            holder = new FruitListAdapter.ViewHolder();

            holder.title = convertView.findViewById(R.id.listitemtitle_singleline);
            holder.description = convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_description);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (FruitListAdapter.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }



        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView title;
        private TextView description;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
        return mPositionsIndexedBySection[section];
    }

    @Override
    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        return mSectionsIndexedByPosition[position];
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getSections() {
        return mSections;
    }

    private void setupSections() {
        String initial = "\0";
        List<String> sections = new ArrayList<>();
        mSectionsIndexedByPosition = new int[mData.size()];
        mPositionsIndexedBySection = new int[mData.size()];

        int section = 0;
        for (int pos = 0; pos < mData.size(); pos++) {
            Fruit fruit = mData.get(pos);
            if (initial.charAt(0) != fruit.getStation().charAt(0)) {
                initial = fruit.getStation().substring(0, 1);
                section = sections.size();
                sections.add(initial);
                mPositionsIndexedBySection[section] = pos;
                mSectionsIndexedByPosition[pos] = section;
            } else {
                mSectionsIndexedByPosition[pos] = section;
            }
        }
        mSections = sections.toArray();
        mPositionsIndexedBySection = Arrays.copyOf(mPositionsIndexedBySection, mSections.length);
    }
}
```

**fragment**

```
public class FragmentFruit extends ListFragment {

    public FragmentFruit() {}

    public static FragmentFruit newInstance() {
        return new FragmentFruit();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_withfastscroll, container, false);
        initialize();
        return view;
    }

    List<Fruit> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private void initialize() {
        String[] items = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fruit_names);
        String[] itemDescriptions = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fruit_descriptions);
        for (int n = 0; n < items.length; n++){
            Fruit fruit = new Fruit();
            fruit.setID();
            fruit.setStation(items[n]);
            fruit.setZone(itemDescriptions[n]);
            list.add(fruit);
        }

        FruitListAdapter mAdapter = new FruitListAdapter(list, getActivity());
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    public static void ChangeColorScrollBar(View Scroll, int Color, Context cxt){

        try
        {
            Field mScrollCacheField = View.class.getDeclaredField("mScrollCache");
            mScrollCacheField.setAccessible(true);
            Object mScrollCache = mScrollCacheField.get(Scroll);
            Field scrollBarField = mScrollCache.getClass().getDeclaredField("scrollBar");
            scrollBarField.setAccessible(true);
            Object scrollBar = scrollBarField.get(mScrollCache);
            Method method = scrollBar.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setVerticalThumbDrawable", Drawable.class);
            method.setAccessible(true);

            Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[1];
            ShapeDrawable sd1 = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
            sd1.getPaint().setColor(cxt.getResources().getColor(Color));
            sd1.setIntrinsicWidth(Math.round(cxt.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dp_3)));
            layers[0] = sd1;

            method.invoke(scrollBar, layers);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = getView();

        mTwoPane = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.detail_container) != null;


        assert v != null;
        ListView lv = v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lv.mScrollCache.scrollBar.setVerticalThumbDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fastscrollthumb_orange));

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not setting the theme anywhere. ListView needs to use that style?

Answer (score -1):

```
 <style name="ListViewStyle.OrangeTheme" parent="android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:fastScrollPreviewBackgroundRight">@drawable/fastscrollpreview_orange</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollOverlayPosition">atThumb</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/fastscrollthumb_orange</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollTextColor">#fff</item>
</style>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset" 
        style="@style/ListViewStyle.OrangeTheme"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This won't work as I need to use a toolbar as the action bar in my activity